# Python pandas to remove header and footer records if detected before converting to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean my data before processing it.
Below is a sample of my data in .txt file format

**Input**

```
20210320
Name|email|age|books|return-date
yuzu|yuzu@gmail.com|23|2020-09-23
apple|apple@gmail.com|27|2021-01-34
Total generated records: 2 rows 
Exported on 2021-03-20
```

**Output - will be converted to dataframe by splitting with |**

```
Name|email|age|books|return-date
yuzu|yuzu@gmail.com|23|2020-09-23
apple|apple@gmail.com|27|2021-01-34
```

How do i remove the header and footer records using python? As i will be processing multiple files and the header and footer might not always appear, the codes need to be able to detect and remove if it is in the text file.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the fact that required rows contain '|' delimiter, you can use this code:

```
f = open("filename.txt",'r',encoding = 'utf-8')
for line in f:
    if '|' not in line:
        continue
    else:
        print(line)
```

**Output**

```
Name|email|age|books|return-date

yuzu|yuzu@gmail.com|23|2020-09-23

apple|apple@gmail.com|27|2021-01-34
```

If you want to remove the new line after each line you can use `print(line.strip())`

**Output**

```
Name|email|age|books|return-date
yuzu|yuzu@gmail.com|23|2020-09-23
apple|apple@gmail.com|27|2021-01-34
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here is the answer. If you tell me what will be the name of your columns, I can edit the columns as well.

```
df = pd.read_csv("yourfilename.txt", skiprows=1,skipfooter=2)
```